# Difference between local and non-local optical model potential?

Tags: optics, nuclear-physics, potential, non-locality

As far as I understand, local OMP (optical model potential) depends only on the relative position, and non-local OMP depends on relative position and momentum.

I am searching for more information so as to understand the difference more intuitively.

Comment: Does this help: @ https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/acb2bc  and   @ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0375947402013210  ?

Comment: Thank you, @BrendanDarrer, for the references. I could find some new references therein for further study. Let's see if I can understand it.